# Cannot create multiple list items in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following array:

```
["uploads-1462948491987.png", "uploads-1462948492004.png"]
```

What I want to achieve is have an unordered list of anchors (inside list items) with image names. I have done the following:

```
var uploadsList = document.querySelector('ul'),
    imageitem = document.createElement('li'),
    anchorTag = document.createElement('a');

anchorTag.setAttribute('href',"#");

var imagesNamesString = "<%= uploads %>";
var imageNames = imagesNamesString.split(',');


imageNames.forEach(function(image) {
    anchorTag.innerHTML = image;
    uploadsList.appendChild(imageitem.appendChild(anchorTag));
});

console.log(imageNames);
```

Problem is, the last image is the only one which appears on the list, what may be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overriding the same element properties on each loop?

Comment: You are overwriting the HTML of your single anchor tag each time: `anchorTag.innerHTML`, so you will only show the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot create multiple list items in javascript

Because you're not creating multiple list items. You're creating one:

```
imageitem = document.createElement('li')
```

...and then using it:

```
uploadsList.appendChild(imageitem.appendChild(anchorTag));
```

where first you append `anchorTag` to the `li`, then immediately move it to the `uploadsList` (because `appendChild` returns the node appended, not the node you called it on). The same for the anchor, you're reusing one, not creating one for each image.

You need to create the `li` and anchor *in* the loop, and append the `li`, not the anchor:

```
imageNames.forEach(function(image) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = "#"; // No need for `setAttribute
    anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(image));
    li.appendChild(anchor);
    uploadsList.appendChild(li);
});
```

```js
var imageNames = ["uploads-1462948491987.png", "uploads-1462948492004.png"];

var uploadsList = document.querySelector('ul');

imageNames.forEach(function(image) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = "#"; // No need for `setAttribute
  anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(image));
  li.appendChild(anchor);
  uploadsList.appendChild(li);
});

document.body.appendChild(uploadsList);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Note that I replaced the use of `innerHTML` with:

```
anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(image));
```

You probably don't want to interpret the image names as HTML. But if you do, just change it back to:

```
anchor.innerHTML = image;
```

Or at that point, really, just

```
imageNames.forEach(function(image) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>" + image + "</a>";
    uploadsList.appendChild(li);
});
```

```js
var imageNames = ["uploads-1462948491987.png", "uploads-1462948492004.png"];

var uploadsList = document.querySelector('ul');

imageNames.forEach(function(image) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>" + image + "</a>";
    uploadsList.appendChild(li);
});

document.body.appendChild(uploadsList);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

But I recommend not treating the image names as HTML (unless you actually put HTML in them).

---

Note that I changed the name `anchorTag` to `anchor`. An element is not a tag. A tag is how we define elements textually in HTML. `<a>` and `</a>` are tags (a start tag and an end tag, respectively); `a` is an element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the structure looks a bit odd though how/where can I add a document.write("<br>"); to make look better?

Comment: @TheBrokenSpanner: There's no reason it should need further breaks, unless you've styled `li` elements in some way. I've added live examples of the options above in case it was an error applying the changes to your code. The structure is a simple list: `<ul><li><a>..></a></li><li><a>...</a></li></ul>`...

Comment: Ok, I have a custom css file so I may have put something earlier. Thanks